# AVX2 VPSHUFB emulation in AVX

Tags: x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

In AVX there's only 128 bits `PSHUFB`

```
VPSHUFB xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128
```

and only AVX2 has the full `PSHUFB` for the whole 256 bits AVX registers

```
VPSHUFB ymm1, ymm2, ymm3/m256
```

**How can this instruction be emulated efficiently with AVX intrinsics?**

Also in this particular case, the source only has 8 elements (bytes) but those could be moved around within the full 32 bytes of the destination. So it's no problem for running just 2 x `PSHUFB`.

A problem I'm finding with `VPSHUFB` is it treats 16 (0x10) as 0, only 128 and up are filled with zero! (highest bit set) Is it possible to do it without adding compares and masking out?

Comment: Probably you didn't notice, but AVX2 `VPSHUFB ymm, ymm, ymm/m256` is not really a 256-bit shuffle, instead it is 2x 128-bit shuffle.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @MaratDukhan has noticed, `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` (i.e. `VPSHUFB` for ymm-s) does not perform full 32-byte shuffle. As for me, it is quite a pity...

That's why in order to emulate it without AVX2 you can simply split each register into two halves, permute each half, then combine together:

```cpp
//AVX only
__m256i _emu_mm256_shuffle_epi8(__m256i reg, __m256i shuf) {
    __m128i reg0 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(reg);
    __m128i reg1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(reg, 1);
    __m128i shuf0 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(shuf);
    __m128i shuf1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(shuf, 1);
    __m128i res0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg0, shuf0);
    __m128i res1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg1, shuf1);
    __m256i res = _mm256_setr_m128i(res0, res1);
    return res;
}
```

If you really want to fully shuffle the 32-byte register, you can follow approach from [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/208237/asplos302-mytkowicz.pdf). Shuffle each half with each half, then blend results together. Without AVX2 it would be something like that:

```cpp
//AVX only
__m256i _emu_mm256_shuffle32_epi8(__m256i reg, __m256i shuf) {
    __m128i reg0 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(reg);
    __m128i reg1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(reg, 1);
    __m128i shuf0 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(shuf);
    __m128i shuf1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(shuf, 1);
    __m128i res00 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg0, shuf0);
    __m128i res01 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg0, shuf1);
    __m128i res10 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg1, shuf0);
    __m128i res11 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(reg1, shuf1);
    __m128i res0 = _mm_blendv_epi8(res10, res00, _mm_cmplt_epi8(shuf0, _mm_set1_epi8(16)));
    __m128i res1 = _mm_blendv_epi8(res11, res01, _mm_cmplt_epi8(shuf1, _mm_set1_epi8(16)));
    __m256i res = _mm256_setr_m128i(res0, res1);
    return res;
}
```

If you know for sure that only the lower half of `reg` is used, then you can remove lines for `reg1`, `res10`, `res11`, and remove comparison and blending. Indeed, it might be more efficient to stick with SSE and use 128-bit registers if you have no AVX2.

The general 32-byte shuffling can be significantly optimized with AVX2:

```cpp
//Uses AVX2
__m256i _ext_mm256_shuffle32_epi8(__m256i reg, __m256i shuf) {
    __m256i regAll0 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(reg, reg, 0x00);
    __m256i regAll1 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(reg, reg, 0x11);
    __m256i resR0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(regAll0, shuf);
    __m256i resR1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(regAll1, shuf);
    __m256i res = _mm256_blendv_epi8(resR1, resR0, _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_set1_epi8(16), shuf));
    return res;
}
```

**Beware**: code not tested!

Comment: Quite a thorough answer, a lot more than I expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you aware that your AVX only implementation contains `_mm256_extracti128_si256`, which is only available in AVX2?

Comment: @stgatilov Check it again, `_mm256_extracti128_si256` compiles to `vextracti128`, which is AVX2. You are talking about `_mm256_extractf128_si256`, which compiles to `vextractf128`. They are similar, but while `vextractf128` operates on floating-point domain,  `vextracti128` operates on integer domain.

Comment: @plasmacel: Sorry, I didn't notice that I used two different extractions. Hopefully, I have fixed this issue now.

Comment: I've tested `_ext_mm256_shuffle32_epi8()` in lots of places in my code and it works well. A must have for anyone working with `__m256i`s a lot.